# POST GET в Python: как POST с массивом номеров и SMS сообщений отправить правильно

Tags: python, post

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать на питоне отправку большого количества сообщений.

Для отправки SMS необходимо вызвать методом POST адрес:

```
https://api.smsworldhub.com/v1/send/multi?token={token}
```

Описание параметров, передаваемых Серверу:

Основные параметры:

```
GET token   Ваш token из профиля.
POST    messages    Отправьте массив с данными: 
- phone 
- mes 
Max 20000 items
```

Дополнительные параметры:

```
POST    lifeTime    Срок жизни SMS 1 - 24 ч.
POST    costUsd Максимальная цена $ за sms.
POST    costRur Максимальная цена руб. за sms.
```

Коды:

```
200 Успешный запрос
400 Ошибка валидации
403 Нет прав
```

В случае успешного запроса Сервер возвращает ответ в виде строки:

```
{"status":"OK","code":200,"data":{"count":20000}}
```

Т.е. просто GET для запроса баланса проходит на ура

```
import requests

my_token = "17982......................."
get_url = "https://api.smsworldhub.com/v1/balance?token=%s" % my_token"
r = requests.get(rurl)
print(r.content)
```

А вот как POST с массивом номеров и сообщений отправить правильно. Методом тыка не осилил.

Comment: API сервиса https://smsworldhub.com/ru/info/api

По одному сообщению получается отправить, но мне надо именно мультиотправку сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что так

```
import requests

my_token = "17982......................."
url = "https://api.smsworldhub.com/v1/send/multi?token=%s" % my_token
message_text = 'Hello!'
phones = ['+79990000001', '+79990000002', '+79990000003']
messages = ({'phone': phone, 'mes': message_text} for phone in phones)
r = requests.post(url, data = {'messages': messages})
print(r.content)
```

Comment: Да, [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) возвращает [генератор](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/). При передаче в `requests.post()` он развернётся в список. Что-то не получается?

Comment: https://python.su/forum/topic/30962/?page=1#post-184178

Comment: Вам нужно обратиться в техподдержку сервиса. В соответствии с их документацией, приведённый мной код должен работать.